# add_filter('the_content', '...') stops pagination from working

Tags: filters, the-content, wp-link-pages

I have a function (it deals with using `preg_replace_callback`to replace Image URLs with URLs/paths to the uploads directory - lets call it `replaceImgUrls()`) which is then passed into `add_filter('the_content', 'replaceImgUrls')`. This works fine and stuff but on posts where I have added pagination (`<!--nextpage-->`), it stops this from working; it fails to split up the pages, but still shows the correct amount of page numbers at the bottom of the content, which you can still click on but each page shows the same content (i.e all the content which is in the post). Here is my function which replaces the image URLs:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'replaceImgURLS');
function replaceImgURLS($content) {
    global $post;
    $content = $post->post_content;
    $newContent = preg_replace_callback(
        '/<img.*src=[\'"]([^\'"]*)/i', 
        function ($match) {
            global $post;
            $imgURL = $match[1];
            $filename   = basename($imgURL) . "-" . $post->ID . ".jpg"; // Create image file name
            $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $postMonth = mysql2date('m', $post->post_date);
            $postYear = mysql2date('Y', $post->post_date);
            $fileURL = $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/' . $postYear . "/" . $postMonth . "/" . $filename;

            return '<img src="' . $fileURL;
        }, 
        $content
    );
    return $newContent;
}
```

When I remove this function from my `functions.php` file, the pagination is restored and works as it should (i.e each page is split up separately). I have `wp_link_pages()` in my `content-single.php` template file.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I worked out what I had to do. @Rarst gave me some guidance which helped massively and I think his idea (in the comments of his question) would work but I haven't actually tested it. Anyway, I fixed it by adding a `$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;` variable in, and, having changed `$content = $post->post_content;` to `$content = get_the_content();`, I passed `$paged` in as a variable, so it's like this: `$content = get_the_content($paged);`. The final code which worked for me looks like this:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'replaceImgURLS');
function replaceImgURLS($content) {
    $post = get_post();
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $content = get_the_content($paged);
    $newContent = preg_replace_callback(
        '/<img.*src=[\'"]([^\'"]*)/i', 
        function ($match) {
            global $post;
            $imgURL = $match[1];
            $filename   = basename($imgURL) . "-" . $post->ID . ".jpg"; // Create image file name
            $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $postMonth = mysql2date('m', $post->post_date);
            $postYear = mysql2date('Y', $post->post_date);
            $fileURL = $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/' . $postYear . "/" . $postMonth . "/" . $filename;

            return '<img src="' . $fileURL;
        }, 
        $content
    );
    return $newContent;
}
```

Hope that helps anyone who comes here by Google or anywhere else :)

Comment: This doesn't quite do anything meaningful `get_the_content($paged)`, first argument to `get_the_content()` is `$more_link_text`.

Comment: yeah I know but it seemed to work for me :/ Possibly because `<!--nextpage-->` acts in a similar way to `<!--more-->` (i.e splits the post up into sections)?

Answer (score 1):

For posts is set up by loop (see [`setup_postdata()`](http://queryposts.com/function/setup_postdata/)) it is split into parts and array of those parts is assigned to global `$pages` variable. Even if it's not paginated this is still where data goes.

Then that variable is actually where [`get_the_content()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_the_content/) looks for post content to process and output, not actual post object.

In your function you are overriding `$content` filter gives you (properly truncated to the page necessary) with complete content from post object. Typically you should stick with acting on data filter gives you, accessing global scope instead of that is very prone to issues like this.

Comment: thanks for the input - I sort of understand what you're saying, but not sure how to act on it - could you elaborate a bit further and tell me what I should do to my code so that the Post is nicely split up into the separate pages again? Thanks :)

Comment: @TomOakley short version (it's two past midnight here :) — don't do `$content = $post->post_content;` this part.

Comment: hey sorry, I didn't reply - I eventually worked out what I had to do, not quite what you said but you set me on the right path so thanks :) I've answered my question with an answer below :)